# Convergence proof in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I would appreciate help with how to proceed to prove the following statement, I have some ideas on how to solve it but do not really get it all together and would appreciate any help/feedback that I can get!

> Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be random variables defined by the relations
> $$P(X_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{n}, \ \ P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{2n}, \ \  P(X_n=-1)=\frac{1}{2n}, \ \ \ n \ge 1.$$ Show that $X_n \xrightarrow[]{p}0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

This is my **thoughts**: First off, I'm sure we need to use the following definition:

**Def**: $X_n$ converges in probability to the random variables X as $n \rightarrow \infty$ iff, for all $\epsilon >0$: $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n\rightarrow \infty.$

Hence, we are goin to prove that $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)\rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then I noted that since we want the absolute value of $X_n$ and $P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=-1)$ we only have to apply the definition on $P(X_n=1)$, is that right? If **yes** we get that: $$P(|X_n|>\epsilon)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n}=0, \ \ 0<\epsilon<1.$$

And then I noticed that the definition only applies for $\epsilon>0$. And since our last relation, $P(X_n=0)$ have $X_n=0$ then $Xn>\epsilon$ cannot be achieved and we can exclude this relation. Here, however, I am very unsure if this is correct.

This is as long as I have come so far. The problem is that even if the above is correct I still only have a proof for $0<\epsilon<1$ and not for all $\epsilon$ greater than zero as the definition says. How should i continue from here?

Comment: You can use that the relation $|X_n| > \varepsilon_1$ implies the relation $|X_n| > \varepsilon_2$ for all $\varepsilon_1 > \varepsilon_2.$ Therefore, the sets $\{|X_n| > \varepsilon\}$ are decreasing on $\varepsilon$ (the larger $\varepsilon$ is, the smaller the set). Therefore, if convergence happens for small $\varepsilon,$ it also happen for bigger $\varepsilon.$ Or better yet, if you prove convergence happens for any one $\varepsilon_0,$ you proved it for all $\varepsilon_1 > \varepsilon_0.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $\epsilon\ge 1$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon)=0
$$
for any $n\ge 1$, and, as you noticed, for $\epsilon\in (0,1)$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon)=\mathsf{P}(X_n\ne 0)=\frac{1}{n}\to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Small correction: $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ should read $\epsilon \in (0,1]$

Comment: May I ask how you concluded that for any $\epsilon \ge 1$ it applies that $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)=0$? Is it because $X_n$ only can assume the values 0, 1 and -1?

Comment: @idlatva Yes. $|X_n|\le 1$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Thank you!